# Parent Scroll-viewer 'Scroll Changed' event firing by Child List-box's Scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, events, scrollview, parent-child

I have a ListBox inside a Scroll Viewer. Scroll Viewer has been attached a Scroll-Changed listener, in which i have placed a:

```
MessageBox.Show("Something Happened!");
```

Here's my WPF code:

```
        <ScrollViewer ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBox>
                    <ListBox.Items>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="item 2"/>
                    </ListBox.Items>
                </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Now problem is that, when i Scroll the ListBox, Somehow ScrollViewer's 'ScrollChanged' event is firing by showing me MessageBox => Something Happened!

I have tried Enabling or Disabling HorizontalScrollBar, but same thing happens...
My VerticalScrollBar is Disabled right now, i made it 'Hidden', but now it also hides the ListBox's Vertical scrollbar and i cannot scroll ListBox by mousewheel also

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hello, I don't understand what the issue is, you listen to a scroll event, and you don't want the code to trigger on this event?

Comment: I don't want the code to trigger to ListBox's Scroll-Changed event. Event is assigned to the outer Scroll Viewer, So, it should trigger code only when we Scroll Parent-ScrollViewer, not when we scroll inner ListBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because [`ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollchanged) is a [routed event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview). Specifically, it's a bubbling event, which means that when it's raised, it goes up the visual tree (from the deeper element where it was raised, up toward the root) looking for handlers.

This lets you do things like this:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="listBox_ScrollChanged"/>
```

Because `ListBox` uses a `ScrollViewer` internally, you can listen for the `ScrollChanged` event at the `ListBox` level and handle it, even though `ListBox` doesn't expose an event for this itself.

Of course, this also leads to situations like the one your're experiencing. Luckily it's easy to solve. In your event handler, you can use [`RoutedEventArgs.Source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventargs.source) to tell which element is being scrolled:

```
//Assuming the ScrollViewer you want to listen to is given the name "OutsideScrollViewer"

private void ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(e.Source,  OutsideScrollViewer))
    {

    }
}
```